# What is the Mysql query for displaying the code of a user defined function in mysql database for mysql version 5.0.45?

Tags: php, mysql, function

Please any body could suggest me as  I am using this query

```
SHOW FUNCTION CODE 'function_name'.
```

But displaying error as given below:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Ya as per the manual I think I have added the single quote for the function. But after removing the quote also gave the same result. I have gone searching online for the issue. Also I need to clarify my MySQL version is 5.0.45.Is this the problem with mysql version or anyother problem? I have also checked in wamp server with mysql version 5.5.8 and here different result displays i.e.
#1289 - The 'SHOW PROCEDURE|FUNCTION CODE' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with '--with-debug' to have it working.What is this now?

Comment: update your sql,heres the bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33637

Answer (score 0):

Use `SHOW FUNCTION CODE function_name`

See MySQL docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-function-code.html

Comment: Thats not working with various result as displayed in different version of mysql